# MS Project Gantt chart: Highlighting today line

Tags: ms-project

How do you highlight this line? It's hard to see in "stock" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options. You can either zoom in by right clicking the chart and selecting zoom, or you can do a right click on blank space in the gantt chart, then  choose "gridlines", then highlight the "current date" and select the line colour.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on a blank space on your Gantt chart, choose "grids ...", highlight "current date," and set the color and line type.

Comment: Hi sonnu, welcome! This answer is the same as [TimmyTurner9's answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/30653/27189) which is already marked as accepted. This means that this is not a good contribution. The only way I can think to save this answer is by editing it and including screenshots of the process. That way it'd bring something new to the table.